# Linux/SSH - get EC2 instance to read local .bashrc file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have a custom `.bashrc` file with color codes locally on my Linux machine running Ubuntu 12.04 for both my user and root.  I connect to Amazon EC2 instances daily running the same distro and would like to somehow use the same `.bashrc` files for my user and root without having to manually create them since we'd like to keep the instances generic seeing as multiple developers ssh to them.

Is it possible to have an EC2 instance read from my local .bashrc file during a session so I can have the same color scheme as my local bash prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible but really not worth the effort. Just copy the file over or create a new file on the EC machine and source it from your `.bashrc` there:

```
. $HOME/home_bashrc
```

You can then delete it whenever you want.

---

Anyway, one way of sourcing your *actual* home `~/.bashrc` is to set up passwordless `ssh` from the EC server to your machine and then add this line to your EC `~/.bash_profile`:

```
scp user@local:/home/user/.bashrc $HOME/home_bash && source $HOME/home_bash
```

Then, add this to your `~/.bash_logout`:

```
rm $HOME/home_bash
```

That way, the file will be deleted as soon as you log out.

Comment: I like deleting it on logout.. Agreed, not worth the effort

Answer (score 1):

Completely untested: if, from the remote server, you can ssh back to your local machine, then you could do:

```
. <(ssh user@local 'cat .bashrc')
```

Or, you could copy your .bashrc to the remote server as `.bashrc_dcd018` and source that.